# Why is my backtracking algorithm not working for this simple problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Hi I am currently trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose you have a random list of people standing in a queue. Each person is described by a pair of integers `(h, k)`, where `h` is the height of the person and `k` is the number of people in front of this person who have a height greater than or equal to h. Write an algorithm to reconstruct the queue.

Note:
The number of people is less than 1,100.

Example

```
Input:
[[7,0], [4,4], [7,1], [5,0], [6,1], [5,2]]

Output:
[[5,0], [7,0], [5,2], [6,1], [4,4], [7,1]]
```

Here is what I have so far as my solution:

```
answer = []
def reconstructQueue(people):
    if len(answer) == len(people) and is_valid(answer):
        return True

    for person in people:
        answer.append(person)
        if is_valid(answer):
            reconstructQueue([x for x in people if x != person])
        else:
            answer.pop()




def is_valid(answer):
    answer = answer[::-1]
    for i in range(len(answer)):
        count = 0
        for j in answer[i+1:]:
            if answer[i][0] <= j[0]:
                count+=1
        if count != answer[i][1]:
            return False
    return True
```

My `is_valid` function is working but the backtracking implemented in `recontructQueue` is going wrong!

Here is how I think it should work:

- Checks if we have a valid answer that contains all the original list values, if so we are done.
- If not then add someone else to the list `answer` and see if that is valid.
- If it is valid then recursively call the function removing the element we just added.
- If it is not valid then we have made a mistake, so we backtrack by popping that element from the answer.

It is not giving me the correct answer though.

Can someone help explain where I am going wrong, I am terrible at backtracking!

Thank you.

Comment: You never check the return value from `reconstructQueue`. You can fix this, but before that you should figure out how long you expect this to take.  If you get 1000 people it could run forever.

Answer (score 0):

Having a global `answer` as part of your recursive inner workings isn't a great idea.  We'll replace it with a defaulted second argument.

As @MattTimmermans notes, you've made the recursion beginner's error of having your recursive function return a useful result but then ignoring that result when you call it recursively.  That recursive call will result in success or failure and you need to act accordingly:

```
def reconstructQueue(people, todo=None):
    if not todo and is_valid(people):
            return people

    if todo is None:
        todo = people
        people = []

    tossed = []

    while todo:
        people.append(todo.pop())

        if is_valid(people):
            result = reconstructQueue(people, todo + tossed)

            if result:
                return result

        tossed.append(people.pop())

    return None  # there is no solution from this starting point

def is_valid(answer):
    for index, (my_height, my_count) in enumerate(answer):
        their_count = sum(my_height <= their_height for their_height, _ in answer[:index])

        if their_count != my_count:
            return False

    return True

scrambled = [(7, 0), (4, 4), (7, 1), (5, 0), (6, 1), (5, 2)]

print(reconstructQueue(scrambled))
```

I've also switched your data structure from a list of lists to a list of tuples as that makes more sense to me Python-wise.

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[(5, 0), (7, 0), (5, 2), (6, 1), (4, 4), (7, 1)]
>
```